# How to get consolidated words post tagging?

Tags: python, nltk, sentiment-analysis, pos-tagger, nltk-book

I am working on a dataset that requires extracting all the words that are adjectives, verbs, and adverbs from each sentence of a data frame column.

This is a sample I was working on to figure out how I could get the desired output.

```
list1=['good','excellent','was','not']
for i in list1:
  x=nltk.pos_tag([i])
  #print(x)
  if (x[0][1] == "JJ" or x[0][1] == "JJS" or x[0][1] == "RB" or x[0][1] == "VB" or x[0][1] == "RBR" or x[0][1] == "RBS" or x[0][1] == "VBN" or x[0][1] == "VBP"):
    print(x)
```

The output it is giving me is:

```
[('good','JJ')]
[('not','RB')]
```

The output I need to get is something like this:

```
good not
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Please dont post code as an image

Comment: @TomMcLean editted!

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a little more specific about what you want to really extract:

---

But here's an attempt.

It seems you're trying to extract verb phrases with adjective/adverbs, if so you can try:

```py
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk import ngrams


text = "this is not good."
tagged_text = pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))


focus_tags = set(['JJ', 'JJS', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS', 'VB', 'VBN', 'VBP'])



for (token1, tag1), (token2, tag2) in ngrams(tagged_text, 2):
    if tag1 in focus_tags and tag2 in focus_tags:
        print(token1 + ' ' + token2)
```

## But that outputs: `is not` and `is not good`!!

Hmmm, in that case, do you want to exact `not good` or `is not good`?

If it's the `is not good` trigram, then try:

```
for (token1, tag1), (token2, tag2), (token3, tag3) in ngrams(tagged_text, 3):
    if tag1 in focus_tags and tag2 in focus_tags and tag3 in focus_tags:
        print(token1 + ' ' + token2 + ' ' + token3)
```

## What if I just want `not good`?

Maybe try removing the verbs? E.g.

```
from nltk import pos_tag, word_tokenize
from nltk import ngrams


text = "this is not good."
tagged_text = pos_tag(word_tokenize(text))


focus_tags = set(['JJ', 'JJS', 'RB', 'RBR', 'RBS'])



for (token1, tag1), (token2, tag2) in ngrams(tagged_text, 2):
    if tag1 in focus_tags and tag2 in focus_tags:
        print(token1 + ' ' + token2)
```